# Reg Serialization and deserialization in boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

In the below serialization and deserialization ,  while desrializing  program is terminating at the line which  is mentioned below..

```
const char *file = "aaa.bin";

std::ofstream outputstring(file,ifstream::binary);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(outputstring,boost::archive::no_header);
int i =1;
oa<< i;
outputstring.close();

std::ifstream intputstring(file,ifstream::binary);
**boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(intputstring);**   //Program is terminating here
int j;
ia >> j;
intputstring.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add same flag to input archive.

```
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(intputstring, boost::archive::no_header);
```